# Is localization or i18n supported in ShieldUI grid component?

Tags: shieldui

Has anyone done i18n (or localization) in ShieldUI Grid JavaScript component?
I need to make column header showing different languages per language setting in browser.
Did research on ShieldUI web site but found nothing.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the value of a column [title](https://www.shieldui.com/documentation/grid/javascript/api/settings/columns/title) in JavaScript, generated depending on the current language.

Comment: In the end I handle I18n from the parent program of this grid component to achieve it.

Comment: Yes, webpage localization almost always involves external settings like locale present in the URL (e.g. /en/xxx, /de/xxx, etc), for SEO-related purposes. Hence, it is very easy to control the localized strings from the page-level javascript.